# Archiving the output from Delete Statement in Sql Server

Tags: sql-server, temp-tables

I'm trying to archive the data into table (EMPTAB_Archive) by deleting the data from Production table (EMPTAB) using the temporary table (##TMP) as a reference.

Note that temporary table contains two fields: empcode and empname, this is a part of code from a stored procedure that isn't working:

```
SELECT @SQL =          'DELETE ET1
                        FROM EMPDB..EMPTAB ET1 DELETED.*
                        INTO [EMPDB_ARCHIVE]..EMPTAB_Archive
                        INNER JOIN ##TMP TMP1
                        WHERE EMPID IN ##TMP
                        AND TMP1.DOCUMENTID = ET1 .EMPID'
         EXEC(@SQL)
```

But i'm getting below error message

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
>   Incorrect syntax near 'DELETED'.
>   Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
>   Incorrect syntax near '##TMP'.

Comment: Was this code copied from a trigger? I think DELETED is a special object that's only available when the trigger fires (like INSERTED and UPDATED).

Comment: Look at the `OUTPUT` clause. What is `WHERE EMPID IN ##TMP` supposed to do? Where is the `ON` clause for the `JOIN`?

Comment: @booyaa copied from a Stored procedure mate

Comment: @MartinSmith  WHERE EMPID IN ##TMP gets only those employee ids that i have retrieved and stored in temporary table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in `WHERE EMPID IN ##TMP`. You have to use join.
Also deleting into is also not correct.

`WHERE EMPID IN ##TMP` must be done by join.

I think that correct SQL should looks like:

```
SELECT @SQL = 'DELETE ET1 OUTPUT DELETED.* 
INTO [EMPDB_ARCHIVE]..EMPTAB_Archive
FROM EMPDB..EMPTAB ET1 
INNER JOIN ##TMP TMP1 ON 
TMP1.DOCUMENTID = ET1 .EMPID'
EXEC(@SQL)
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you do not need Dynamic SQL which is in this case subject to SQL Injection. Just use Static SQL

Comment: Correct, you can execute this without dynamic SQL.